# Postman to open browser and fetch data from website into request parameter

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

Is it possible for postman(App not Chrome extension) scripts to open an external browser and fetch data from the website (In my case a Temp Pin) as a request parameter?

I did search on the web and didn't found any leads except that POSTMAN now supports opening external browser starting version 6.1.2.